# The @model directive in view does not bind the View model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The application is .Net Framework 3.5 and MVC Framework 1.0
The controller has:

```
namespace MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.Controllers
{
    public class WorkFlowTestController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /WorkFlowTest/

        public ActionResult OpenSubmission(string processId, string mailId)
        {
            var SubmissionModelView = new MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel{processInstance =processId,  mail =mailId} ;
            return View("Submission", SubmissionModelView);
        }
    }
}
```

The View Model has

```
namespace MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels
   {
    public class WorkFlowTestViewModel
    {
        public string processInstance { get; set; }
        public string mail { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

The view has:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
@model MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The model directive is not recognized and @Model. does not give the option  processInstance and mail

What am I missing , the bind to view is not happening. Please can some one help.

Comment: Razor is not an available view engine for MVC 1.0.  You will have to stick with the WebForms view engine.

Comment: Why in the world would you be using MVC 1.0?  In .NET 3.5 you can use MVC 2.0 which is a far sight better than MVC 1.0.

Comment: @Erik Good Point can you help- I see both MVC 1 and MVC 2 on my machine how do I add MVC2 to my project instead of MVC 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `@model` is for the Razor views, but it looks like you might be using it in an .aspx page view.

You should instead try supplying the type like this:

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MockBDPWorkflowTestApp.ViewModels.WorkFlowTestViewModel>`

see if that works.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't thing strong model typing was introduced until MVC2.  So I don't think the Templated ViewPage<T> exists in MVC 1.